# Fix “compile error: next without for” error in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I cant seem to figure out this. I would like to search my worksheets to see if there is a "=REF!" and if there is a error to not run my code. The problem with it is that when I run it the error in the code is revolved around the next part

```
Sub logs()

Dim numberofsheets As Integer

For numberofsheets = 1 To 5

Set checkRange = Sheets("Final Four").Range("A1:Z100")
 If IsError(CheckCell) And _
       CVErr(CheckCell) = CVErr(2023) Then
Exit Sub
End If

Next

Set checkRange = Sheets("Top Left").Range("A1:Z100")
 If IsError(CheckCell) And _
       CVErr(CheckCell) = CVErr(2023) Then
Exit Sub
End If

Next

Set checkRange = Sheets("Bottom Left").Range("A1:Z100")
 If IsError(CheckCell) And _
        CVErr(CheckCell) = CVErr(2023) Then
Exit Sub
End If

Next

Set checkRange = Sheets("Top Right").Range("A1:Z100")
 If IsError(CheckCell) And _
       CVErr(CheckCell) = CVErr(2023) Then
Exit Sub
End If

Next

Set checkRange = Sheets("Bottom Right").Range("A1:Z100")
 If IsError(CheckCell) And _
       CVErr(CheckCell) = CVErr(2023) Then
Exit Sub
End If

ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = True

lst = Sheets("data").UsedRange.Rows.Count
x = lst + 1

        ' Display a message when one of the designated cells has been
        ' changed.
        ' Place your code here.
        Sheets("data").Range("A" & x) = ActiveSheet.Range("I3")
        Sheets("data").Range("B" & x) = ActiveSheet.Range("I4")


End Sub
```

Not sure how to do this. I'm very new at it.

Comment: You only have one `For` statement, but four `Next` statements.  Remove three of the `Next` statements.

Comment: Okay, how do I do this?

Comment: @YowE3K wow you're fast this morning

Comment: Actually, you don't even seem to be using the loop.  So just remove one `For` statement and four `Next` statements.

Comment: What is `CheckCell`, and where do you set it?

Comment: When I get rid of the next statements and for statement. The code doesn't recognize the =REF! error in my workbook and still records the I3 and I4 into my data sheet

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like the `For` loop below to implement in your code:

```
Sub logs()

Dim Sht As Worksheet
Dim checkRange As Range, CheckCell As Range

For Each Sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets ' loop through your worksheets
    With Sht
        Select Case .Name  ' check for the sheet.Name
            Case "Final Four", "Top Left", "Bottom Left", "Top Right", "Bottom Right"
                Set checkRange = .Range("A1:Z100") ' set the range for the current sheet

                For Each CheckCell In checkRange
                    If IsError(CheckCell) Then
                        If CheckCell.Value = CVErr(2023) Then Exit Sub

                        ' you can use the following syntax as well
                        If CheckCell.Value = CVErr(xlErrRef) Then Exit Sub
                    End If
                Next CheckCell
                Set checkRange = Nothing
            Case Else
                ' do nothing

        End Select
    End With
Next Sht

' rest of your code


End Sub
```

Comment: @YowE3K tru that, just tested it again with a different scenario

Comment: it says there is anerror on thisIf IsError(CheckCell) And CVErr(CheckCell) = CVErr(2023) Then

Comment: @YowE3K I love a lot of lines, I charge by quantity(amout of lines) not quality

Comment: What if I want all my sheets to refresh so then sometimes there isn't a =REF! and then my code works? Because right now I have all my code on a refresh button and I want my data to refresh each time no matter what when I press the refresh button but if the data has a =REF! then to not input my i3 and i4 into my data sheet

Comment: @B.Harm this sound like a great New Post for **SO**. As for now, I think my answer has answered your current post.

Comment: @YowE3K i prefer to use `If CheckCell.Value = CVErr(xlErrRef)`